# sending mail from java smtpapi

Tags: java, smtp

I am trying to send a mail using a Java program and JavaMailApi. I have written this program and having a local SMTPServer. This is not a problem.  I don't know what to  put in host address. Please have a look at my code and let me know what should I do?

```
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;
    import javax.activation.*;

// Send a simple, single part, text/plain e-mail
    public class TestEmail {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        // SUBSTITUTE YOUR EMAIL ADDRESSES HERE!!!
            String to = "vipan@vipan.com";
            String from = "vipan@vipan.com";
        // SUBSTITUTE YOUR ISP'S MAIL SERVER HERE!!!
            String host = "smtp.yourisp.net";

        // Create properties, get Session
            Properties props = new Properties();

        // If using static Transport.send(),
        // need to specify which host to send it to
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        // To see what is going on behind the scene
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

            try {
            // Instantiatee a message
                Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            //Set message attributes
                msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
                msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
                msg.setSubject("Test E-Mail through Java");
                msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // Set message content
                msg.setText("This is a test of sending a " +
                        "plain text e-mail through Java.\n" +
                        "Here is line 2.");

            //Send the message
                Transport.send(msg);
        }
            catch (MessagingException mex) {
            // Prints all nested (chained) exceptions as well
                mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}//End of class
```

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know what to put in host address.

Host address is the your SMTP server's IP address or domain name.

Comment: but I told I have a SMTP server software. what to do in this case if I want to chk my program is able to connect or not ..

Comment: @atul: Try giving IP or domain name of machine on which you have SMTP server software resides as host address.

Answer (score 0):

Host is

```
smtp.gmail.com
```

for gmail

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

it should work .
But remember for these mailing api to work, you should enable pop3 and smtp from your gmail account. And no extra settings ( like 2-way security login prevents any one to use smtp/pop3 from other apis ).

Comment: it would work only if I have internet connection but I have to just chk that my program will wrk or not on a machine having no internet connection

Comment: then try your ip address there. Or no idea since I have not tested it on my own mailing system .